# Utilizar REGEX para reemplazar el signo de pregunta ? en un texto, utilizando Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, regex

estoy utilizando VB.NET y utilizo el famoso comando "REGEX" que entiendo que es universal para encontrar texto dentro de un string, lo que quiero reemplazar la palabra que sigue al signo de pregunta! he logrado reemplazar con una arroba por delante que es el siguiente

```
(@\w*)
```

Pero lo que deseo es reemplazar una palabra con signo de pregunta por delante y no logro encontrar la forma de hacerlo Al utilizar **REGEX** he logrado encontrar una palabra precedida por arroba dentro de un texto por ejemplo:

> Yo tengo un @rbol verde

Y la palabra encontrada seria "@rbol"
Y lo que deseo que se encuentre la palabra con el signo de pregunta ?
Por ejemplo

> Yo tengo un ?arbol verde

Y la palabra que se encuentre sea"?arbol"

¡Alguien me puede ayudar? resulta que el signo de pregunta es utilizado para otro comando y se me mezcla la interpretación! Quiero encontrar una palabra precedida del signo? (el de cerrar pregunta).
Saben algo al respecto? espero respuesta muchas gracias

Se puede realizar una prueba en la siguiente página:

> https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para hallar palabras que empiecen con el signo de interrogación ***?***, incluyendo dicho signo en el hallazgo, la expresión regular más corta sería `\?\w*`. La barra invertida que precede a `?` funciona como 'carácter de escape' que indica en este caso que el metacarácter siguiente, es decir `?`, debe interpretarse literalmente y no como metacarácter. También funciona definir un conjunto de caracteres con un solo carácter, como en `[?]`, pero `\?` es equivalente y más corto.

Si se requiere que después de ***?*** haya 'realmente' una palabra en lugar de un espacio u otro límite de palabras, la expresión debería ser `\?\w+` donde `\w+` especifica 'uno o más' caracteres de palabra, mientras que `\w*` significa '0 o más' caracteres de palabra.

Si el signo ***?*** no debe hacer parte de la cadena encontrada, y esta tuviera que contener al menos un carácter depués del interrogante, la expresión regular debería ser `(?<=\?)\w+` en la que la expresión entre paréntesis se interpreta como una comprobación hacia atrás ("lookbehind"). Dicha expresión regular podría leerse como "encontrar palabras precedidas por el signo de interrogación pero sin incluir dicho signo en el hallazgo".

Answer (score 0):

La solución al problema es la siguiente, Después de un buen rato de leer la documentación pude entender

```
(?:[?]\w*)
```